How do you change the scroll highlight color in bookdown using style.css?
Bookdown has a cool built in feature where the side bar automatically highlights in blue the section that you're currently scrolling past or reading. However, I can't figure out how to change the color in the style.css page. If I use a:link it completely removes the scroll highlight feature.



/*style.css*/

/* Basic styling for the sidebar */
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Custom style for the active sidebar link */
.nav-link.active {
    background-color: #007bff; /*desired highlight background color */
    color: #ffffff; /* Text color when active */
    font-weight: bold; /* Optional: Make the text bold*/
}

/*Main content area*/
.content {
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding: 20px;
}
    <div class="bookdown">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section1" class="nav-link">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2" class="nav-link">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3" class="nav-link active">Section 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section4" class="nav-link">Section 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1 id="section1">Section 1</h1>
            <p>Content for section 1.</p>
            <h1 id="section2">Section 2</h1>
            <p>Content for section 2.</p>
            <h1 id="section3">Section 3</h1>
            <p>Content for section 3.</p>
            <h1 id="section4">Section 4</h1>
            <p>Content for section 4.</p>
        </div>
    </div>




HTML :

The sidebar is a simple list of links <ul class="nav"> where one of the links has the active class.
The content div contains the sections of the page.

CSS:

.nav-link styles the basic appearance of the links in the sidebar.
.nav-link.active styles the active link, changing its background color to blue #007bff and text color to white #ffffff. You can adjust these colors to your preference.
